# Android Service in a library not being updated when shared by two applications

Tags: android, service, sharing

I've got two separate applications that use a common background service (which is in a common library which both applications include) to collect Bluetooth data. Everything works fine on first installation of the applications.

The problem is that when one of the applications is re-deployed after having the common service changed, it still uses the service previously installed.

Here's some info and an example to clarify things:
The 2 applications are named BioSound, and BioZen. Each of them includes a common library called AndroidSpineServerLib, which in terns includes the common library AndroidBTService (which contains the background service)

For example, on first installation AndroidBTService has a version number of, say 1.0. When the applications are deployed everything is fine, Both BioZen and BioSound uses the V1.0 service.

Then I make a change to BioSound, and AndroidBTService, incrementing it's version to V1.1. When I deploy BioSound after this I would expect it to use the newly changed service V1.1, but it continues to use the V1.0 service. The only way to fix this is to remove the BioZen , then BioSound  the correct service ( I don't even have to reinstall BioSound).

Programatically, when I start each application I bind to the service, and when each application exits I unbind the service.

Obviously I'm missing something but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you are using an implicit intent to communicate with your service that doesn't specific an application, only an action. That intent (which you're using in both applications) ends up getting resolved to one particular application's service. Instead, make sure to specify the explicit intent with the particular component or class. See the [Intent docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is it but I'm having difficulty with the details.

Here's the existing code:

```
Mainfest for the main Application:
<application android:icon="@drawable/biosound_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <service    
        android:name="com.t2.biofeedback.BioFeedbackService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.t2.biofeedback.IBioFeedbackService"/>         
        </intent-filter>       
    </service>
</application>
```

The call to bind the service was in the library AndroidSpineServerLib

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.t2.biofeedback.IBioFeedbackService");
bindService(intent2, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

So I can see how the service was bound to a specific application

To fix this I tried:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, BioFeedbackService.class);  
bindService(intent2, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

The problem is that the service was not created.

I also tried the following

```
In the manifest of the service:

    <service    
        android:class=".service.BioFeedbackService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.t2.biofeedback.IBioFeedbackService"/>         
        </intent-filter>       
    </service>

And in the library where I bind the service:    

    Intent intent2 = new Intent();
    intent2.setAction("com.t2.biofeedback.IBioFeedbackService");
    bindService(intent2, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Still no luck.

Maybe I'm putting the service definition in the wrong manifest.
Remember I have the following hierarchy

```
Main Application references:
    AndroidBTService (Library), which references 
    AndroidSpineServerLib (Library)


So I have 3 manifests and not sure which to update.
```